# Addition of ideals, properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Suppose $A,B,C$ are ideals of a (commutative ring with unity) $R$, $a\in A, b \in B$. Is it true that if $(a+b)\in C$, then $a,b \in C$? Thanks for any replies.

Comment: Counterexample: choose $\,a\not\in C\,$ and $\,b = -a,\ $ for example $\,a = 1\ $ (assuming $\,C\ne (1) = R).$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $2 \in 2 \mathbb{Z}$ and $3 \in 3 \mathbb{Z}$. (These are ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$.) Then $2+3=5 \in 5 \mathbb{Z}$ while $2, 3 \not\in 5\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Sorry, but what is 2Z and 3Z, and what are they ideals of? I'm new to the concept!

Comment: Ok so 2Z is multiples of 2, 2+3 is in 5Z but 2, 3 are not. Alright thanks.